# Q-learning: What is the correct state for reward calculation

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

## Q learning - rewards

I'm struggling to interpret the pseudocode for the Q learning algorithm:

```
1  For each s, a initialize table entry Q(a, s) = 0
2  Observe current state s
3  Do forever:
4     Select an action a and execute it
5     Receive immediate reward r
6     Observe the new state s′ ← δ(a, s)
7     Update the table entry for Q(a, s) as follows:
8        Q( a, s ) ← R( s ) + γ * max Q( a′, s′ )
9     ￼￼￼￼￼￼s ← s′
```

Should the rewards be collected from the subsequent state `s'` or the current state `s`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rewards should be collected from the **subsequent state** you enter after executing the action `a`.